# how to find the difference b/w to dates stored in a variable in shell script ( KSH shell )

Tags: shell, ksh, hp-ux

In hp-ux as there is no GNU `date` available, i.e the `-d` and `-s` options of the `date` command are not available. How do I find the difference between two given dates in days (as we do in Solaris or bash shell)?

Comment: What format are the dates in?

Comment: they are in the format dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: And you want the difference in decades/months/hours/microseconds...? You need to be a little more specific about what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want the difference in days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually many solutions to be found via Google, but [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42415/36514) is one that I just stumbled across and like for its brevity. You would use its `ansi_dn` function on both dates and calculate the difference.

`diff_dates.sh`:

```
#!/bin/ksh

. ./ansi_dn.sh

date_to="$1"
date_from="$2"

echo $((
      $(ansi_dn \
        $(echo "${date_to}"   | cut -d/ -f3) \
        $(echo "${date_to}"   | cut -d/ -f2) \
        $(echo "${date_to}"   | cut -d/ -f1) \
      )
    - $(ansi_dn \
        $(echo "${date_from}" | cut -d/ -f3) \
        $(echo "${date_from}" | cut -d/ -f2) \
        $(echo "${date_from}" | cut -d/ -f1) \
      )
))
```

(If you have the years, months and days of both dates in separate variables already the `cut` nightmare is not needed, obviously.)

Example:

```
$ ./diff_dates.sh 08/05/2013 01/01/1939
27156
```

Let's verify correctness with GNU `date`:

```
$ echo $(( ( $(date -d 2013-05-08 +%s) - $(date -d 1939-01-01 +%s) + 43200 ) / 86400))
27156
```

Comment: but what are contents of the script ansi_dn.sh in the above code

Comment: @KVR_GROUPS: The function that I linked to in the first sentence, found in this answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42415/36514

Comment: Can you explain it, please ?

Comment: Explain what exactly? You copy the function I linked to your script and call it like I showed in my answer.

Comment: can u say what exactly its doing as  i am not understanding those weird lines of the code